# Was HTTP status code 308 ("Permanent Redirect") introduced in HTTP 2?

Tags: http, http-status-codes, http-status-code-308

I have [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46100802/qnetworkaccessmanager-doesnt-handle-http-status-code-308) that Qt doesn't support status code 308. I was wondering why that is. I'm also aware that [not all subtasks](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-50956) of the "Implement HTTP 2" Qt task are completed. So, if 308 was introduced in HTTP 2, I will beware that doing a custom implementation of 308 in my Qt app might be near-impossible.

I have checked the [HTTP 1.1 spec](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) and it seems 308 is absent there.

Am I right in deducing 308 was introduced in HTTP 2?

Answer (score 2):

1) RFC 2616 isn't "the" HTTP spec anymore. It has been obsoleted a few years ago by RFCs 7230 etc.

2) Status codes do not need to be defined in the base specs; 308 is defined in RFC 7538. The list of assigned status codes is at https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml

3) And no, there's no direct relation to HTTP/2. In general, status codes are independent of the protocol version.